# Properly setting up Apache2 to avoid upload timeouts with Microsoft OneDrive

Tags: apache

I have a simple Perl script that uploads a file from an HTML form, and it does works.  i.e Uploads a file from my local Mac HD to my web server via a webpage.

What I have noticed, however, if I try to upload files from Microsoft's OneDrive I am more likely to get the following info below. I have no problems using my OneDrive via Mac's Finder, or my iPhone, etc.

**access.log**

> [14/Feb/2022:23:36:51 -0500] "POST /cgi-bin/upload2.pl HTTP/1.1" 408
> 487 "http://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X
> 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.2
> Safari/605.1.15"

**error.log**

> [Mon Feb 14 23:37:02.121496 2022] [cgi:error] [pid 3734:tid
> 140367391328000] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client
> -.-.-.-:58184] AH01225: Error reading request entity data, referer: http://example.com/

My Apache2 settings are:

```
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
```

At my slim level of knowledge of Apache, I am assuming that my problem is all about timing. If that's the case, can I change settings above to help? Or am I off base?

*One small thing I noticed, but I don't know if it means anything

My web browser says:

> Server timeout waiting for the HTTP request from the client. and it
> mentions port 80.

However, in the error.log it mentions port 58184. I don't know if that's normal, due to routers, other routine behavior.

Comment: I have the same error message but from different circumstances. When the requests to the server overflow it's ability to service them, it seems to generate these messages in the error log (Apache/2.4.51 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1l). I don't know what's causing this. I have Timeout 1800, KeepAlive On, MaxKeepAliveRequests 0, KeepAliveTimeout 60.

Answer (score 0):

Set KeepAlive to Off - it seems to have a detrimental effect with busy Apache servers.